# How to properly extract generic parameters of function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Usually I use Typescript's `Parameters` to receive all parameters required by a function of a class:

```
get = (...params: Parameters<Controller["get"]>) => {}
```

It works just fine with predefined types in function signature like this: `get(id: number)`.

I'm currently trying to get parameters of function that has the following signature:

```
functionName<T>(callback: () => Promise<T>)
```

But with the `Parameters` it supposes that the `T` is `never` and I can't pass my own `T` into the parameters of such arrow function to get something like `Parameters<Controller["get"]<T>>` to get proper generic when I call my function like in the beginning.

Edit 1: Minimal Reproducible Example

```
class Test {
    genericFunction<T>(obj: T): T {return obj;}
    genericFunctionPromise<T>(c: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {return c();}

    example(params: Parameters<Test["genericFunction"]>) {};
    examplePromise(params: Parameters<Test["genericFunctionPromise"]>) {params};
}
```

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Comment: Please make the code here into a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue without requiring extra work.  This includes a definition of `Controller`, the declaration of `functionName`, and any surrounding code to make it compiler.  If you have a value of the generic function type you can use instantiation expressions to pass it a generic parameter without calling it.  Otherwise you'd have to fake it up somehow.  I'll know more when I see a [mre]

Comment: @jcalz I've added now

Comment: (Do you mean `...params` instead of `params`?) You can try [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2PzVm) but there's a bug in TS4.7 that prevents it from compiling without errors; that bug is fixed in nightly and will be released with TS4.8.  Does this approach address your question?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that's exactly what I wanted, the `Parameters<typeof this.genericFunctionPromise<T>>` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript 4.7 introduced [instantiation expressions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#instantiation-expressions) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47606](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607), so if you have a value `f` of a generic function type, you can specify the type parameters of that function without  calling it.  Let's say your function declaration is

```
declare function f<T, U>(x: T, y: U): [T, U];
```

Then you can instantiate `T` and `U` with, say, `number` and `string`, to get a new expression:

```
const g = f<number, string>; // instantiation expression
// const g: (x: number, y: string) => [number, string]
```

You can even use [the `typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) to get the type of such a expression without actually creating one:

```
type G = typeof f<number, string>;
// type G = (x: number, y: string) => [number, string]
```

Unfortunately, you can't do this *purely* at the type level (see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607#issuecomment-1058192563) on ms/TS#47606).  You need that variable `f`, or a property of a variable.  If you only have the type of `f`, then you can't instantiate its type parameters

```
type F = typeof f;
// type F = <T, U>(x: T, y: U) => [T, U]

type Nope = F<number, string>; // error, F is not generic!
```

---

Luckily, inside of `Test`, you *do* have a value of the generic function type you care about.  It's `this.genericFunction` or `this.genericFunctionPromise`:

```
class Test {
  genericFunction<T>(obj: T): T { return obj; }
  genericFunctionPromise<T>(c: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> { return c(); }

  example<T>(
     ...params: Parameters<typeof this.genericFunction<T>>) {
     // error ------------------> ^^^^
  } 
  examplePromise<T>(
    ...params: Parameters<typeof this.genericFunctionPromise<T>>
    // error ------------------> ^^^^
  ) { params } 
}        

new Test().examplePromise(() => Promise.resolve(100));
// (method) Test.examplePromise<number>(c: () => Promise<number>): void
```

And that actually works... except that there are errors on `this` in TypeScript 4.7.  Ugh.  This turns out to be a bug in TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#49451](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49451).  This bug has been fixed at [microsoft/TypeScript#49521](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49521), so `typescript@next` nightly build will work, and it will be released with TypeScript 4.8.

If you need to get this working in TS4.7, you could declare a fake variable of type `Test` and use it instead, since we just care about types:

```
declare const __test: Test; // fake

class Test {
  genericFunction<T>(obj: T): T { return obj; }
  genericFunctionPromise<T>(c: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> { return c(); }

  example<T>(
    ...params: Parameters<typeof __test.genericFunction<T>>) {
  }
  examplePromise<T>(
    ...params: Parameters<typeof __test.genericFunctionPromise<T>>) {
    params
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIB4AVAGngFUA+ACgA8AueU+AT0fIEpGBtZ8gXQDcAKDB4AzhngBzeAF5CqZAFsARiBhlJMLKmmURAekPwxqSTMZ1GStRrJt423dI7zK8brfWanGHXr8wsIYLAAOCADi8vChETiIiio+Wv4uBsLGseFRMdbw3vasjM56bnIeXslFpdJBITnwAGIxcSAJSEYmbc0xxGRU+cyOnO6efPU9AHI4ETFNBIW+tQbwWRowOL4tWOIFOFLSIKgaWGAAhMGgkLAIZhYA+g8YIJKMRK8YIqLQ4nsfFgA3sJ4DJjqcwE00JhcKhiDQcKoAFbvLhMeCA+BwDDIGD4RFIwTwAC+ILBJx0kOh2DwAAVNspdiB4dQwFZyh56ThGeJmURKGiuTy+R5MdjcfgwNQOETSWSQLQoMowhARdQyaCAHTasKwJXiRi0vXKEAvGDiAhtDpPF6STVHClnKHoGlw-kCjFk0mghVKlUgIVMlka+DazW6mD6w3G00aC1WxI2z728GU50wukMoPutzA0GgiP6r3COUnADuTE+0s1vuVqsDvOo0rGDZAmrg4hwEAAbiBqABGAAMg44MsyJmoJowAAscMA3ACMDXFXWA1neYtqjAaGz4M2KvBW5u7Nu0d2cFhgPAgA)